# How to prevent my wordpress requesting jquery from another ip?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

My wordpress is infected by malware. I found malicious code attached right after jquery codes in every js file.

Also I found multiple requests being made to unknown host/ip. I'm unable to find which script makes this call.

So I'm thinking to block any request to third party domain or IP via htaccess. But it doesn't seem to work.

Please advice the correct way to write this.

path to .`htaccess` file:

```
public_html\.htaccess
```

The content if it (**before changes**):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried:

> attempt 1
>   //but I don't think this is relevant as it's meant for incoming
>   requests

order allow,deny
    allow from all
    deny from 134.249.116.78

> attempt 2

Deny from 134.249.116.78

This is how network tab looks like:

[image]

And the header like this:

[image]

Comment: can you try this Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 134.249.116.78  line break after Allow

Comment: This is like putting a band-aid on a broken arm. You need to wipe the server, not block outgoing requests.

Comment: (and as these are client-side requests, blocking them server-side does **nothing**)

Comment: @VaibhavSoni, internal server occured. My domain not accessible.

Comment: Don't try to 'fix' it this way. I'm sorry, but even for experienced persons it's hard to remove these kinds of malware, and not to be offensive, but you do not seem very experienced. The best option would be to get a clean start (and keep everything updated!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to fix the server per https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server.

Comment: @ceejayoz, so the best way is to find the script?

Comment: @112233 The best way is to wipe the server and restore from a backup from before the hack. Even if you find one script, you can't trust this server again. See https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server.

Comment: @ceejayoz, alright. noted.

Comment: @112233 may be you are adding at wrong place.

Comment: Install wordfence plugin, and IF you're lucky, it might remove it for you. Be advised however, it might come back later, if you don't fix.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to do this at the Web Server level of your stack. In your case using Apache configuration.

Specifically, the important one for your question is:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Additionally for the issue of XSS

```
 Header set X-XSS-Protection “1; mode=block”
```

It should be noted that is not all that is necessary to lock down a server and that will not stop all XSS but it is a step towards a more secure server environment.

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with frames, and blocking client-side requests server-side is useless. Some JS on the site is making client browsers make calls - it's not coming to or from the server.

Comment: The web server in use will define what JS connections are allowed in the viewport being rendered.

Comment: The webserver will do nothing to interfere with `<script src="http://134.249.116.78/jquery.js"></script>`, which is basically what's happening to OP. There's no XSS and no frames here.

Comment: Well you could scrape it out with the web server actually, sorry I just didn't fully understand what was being asked before.